# Как установить иконку окна браузера?

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Как установить свою картинку для приложения с помощью GWT? Для заголовков сразу нашел - [Window.setTitle](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#setTitle(java.lang.String)), а для setIcon ничего подобного нет :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Современные браузеры не требуют обязательно указывать мета-тег для favicon" .. Это так! Вы только взгляните в error.log апача, если этой иконки в корне нет - увидите массу ошибок обращения к несуществующему файлу.
А вот это:

```
<LINK rel="icon" href="favicon_01.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

очень удобно будет использовать если нужно поставить разные иконки на страницах одного сайта.

Comment: Совершенно согласен =)

Answer (score 4):

Если вы про favicon, то пропишите в head

```
<LINK rel="icon" href="путь_к_иконке" type="image/x-icon">
<LINK rel="shortcut icon" href="путь_к_иконке" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: А чем отличается rel=icon от rel=shortcut icon? В интернете не нашел ответа :(

Comment: По ссылке ниже же все описано. 'shortcut icon' - это для IE

Answer (score 3):

Либо просто положить в корень сайта статический файл favicon.ico

http://www.google.com/favicon.ico

Comment: Илья, как так просто положить в корень сайта иконку? После того как положишь в папку на сервер иконку, ее нужно будет подключить, вставив в шаблон хтмл код, который написали вверху.

Comment: [Современные браузеры не требуют обязательно указывать мета-тег для favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)

> Originally, the favicon was a file called favicon.ico placed in the root directory (e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/favicon.ico) of a web site.

И далее:

> favicon.ico located in the web site's root ... Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes