# Добавление логотипа

Tags: html

Как добавить логотип к названию сайта в `<title>`?

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: <link rel="icon" href="путь к картинке" type="image/x-icon">

Comment: Надеюсь не надо объяснять, что строку выше надо поместить в `head`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/16453/186083

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая иконка называется [favicon](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon). 
Как добавить иконку сайта: [инструкция](http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-dobavit-ikonku-sayta-v-adresnuyu-stroku-brauzera).

Пример:
(атрибут href - путь к иконке)

```
<head>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
```

Генератор иконок для сайта (Favicons, Touch Icons, Tile Icons) под разные размеры, ОС и браузеры: [ссылка](https://realfavicongenerator.net/)